# HEX to 7 segment decoder for a common anode 7 SEG display

Tags: digital-logic, 7segmentdisplay

is there any integrated circuit HEX to 7 segment decoder for a common anode 7 SEG display that generates codes to display hex digits from 0 to F as shown in the photo. Thanks[image]

Comment: Yes. You should be able to find it by searching.

Comment: I may have spoken too soon. There used to be such, but I believe they are now all discontinued.

Comment: Do you need this for board repair? ...new design? ...just because you have these LED displays? The answers may be different for each.

Comment: There used to be a TIL311 which displayed hex format, but it has long been deprecated from the market. If you find any they cost ten times the original cost.

Comment: use microcontroller. Demux the pins to drive all displays together.

Answer (score 3):

Not aware of any standard 74xx chip solution.  My recommendation is to use a low-end microcontroller that has at least 11 GPIO pins.  The hex to 7-segment conversion can be done with a lookup table (array) and a few lines of code.

Comment: I'am using PIC16F84A which contains 13 pins and i have a 6 digit multiplexed 7 SEG display which need 6 pins to select digits, so it remains just 7 pins. I tried 74xx series but their problem they display digits 6 and 9 in a different format not like i want as mentioned in the photo .

Comment: If your display is LCD, you could AY0438 segment drivers.  Their input is serial (SPI) which would free up i/o pins on the MCU.

Answer (score 2):

besides the microcontroller suggested by AlmostDone you can use a small EEPROM with (at least) 4 address pins and 7 data pins.

You can tie any unused address pins to ground.

Comment: I'am using PIC16F84A which contains 13 pins and i have a 6 digit multiplexed 7 SEG display which need 6 pins to select digits, so it remains just 7 pins. I tried 74xx series but their problem they display digits 6 and 9 in a different format not like i want as mentioned in the photo